# Get the latest record by date for a user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I've two tables

```
user_conversation
-----------------
id
from_user_id
to_user_id
item_id
offer_detail_id
message_type
deleted_by_sender
deleted_by_receiver

user_conversation_reply
-----------------------
id
from_user_id
message_text
sent_date
conversation_id
is_read
```

Whenever a new conversation starts against any item a record will be entered in the user_conversation_table and message will be recorded in the user_conversation_reply table for that conversation. Similarly, different messages can be added for that conversation in the user_conversation_table.

I want to get the all the conversation of a user. (i.e. from_user_id,to_user_id,item_id makes up a combination) and along with that I need to have the last message of this conversation.

```
user_conversation 

id     from_user_id     to_user_id     item_id
1           8              2             1

user_conversation_reply 

id     from_user_id     message     conversation_id   sent_date
1           8              helo             1         2014-12-07
2           8           how r u             1         2014-12-08
```

A user can be a part of multiple conversation. So, I want to get the last conversation message of each conversation of a user.

I'm using this query to filter out the records for a user.

```
Select * from user_conversation where to_user_id = 2;
```

Please, suggest.

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that `user_conversation_reply.id` is an auto-incremented primary key, 
and the last message has always the highest `id`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  Select uc.id, max( ucr.id ) max_ucr
  from user_conversation uc
  JOIN user_conversation_reply ucr ON ucr.conversation_id = uc.id
  where uc.to_user_id = 2
  GROUP BY uc.id
) q
JOIN user_conversation uc ON q.id = uc.id
JOIN user_conversation_reply ucr ON q.max_ucr = ucr.id
;
```